SVM training taking too long
I have a dataset with 41 features, out of which 4 are text features. I've been given "Bag of Words" numpy arrays (npz) for these four features, which I combined with the other numerical features to train an SVM model. There are a total of 100000 records and 41 features, 4 of which are vectorized as mentioned.
This model has been training for 45 minutes now :). Is there a way to decrease training time? Is there anything wrong with how I pre-process the dataset (particularly combine npz and existing numerical features)? Any other options that I could explore?
title_feature = load_npz('train_title_bow.npz')
overview_feature = load_npz('train_overview_bow.npz')
tagline_feature = load_npz('train_tagline_bow.npz')
production_companies_feature = load_npz('train_production_companies_bow.npz')

numerical_features = df_train[df_train.columns.difference(['title', 'overview', 'tagline', 'production_companies', 'rate_category', 'average_rate', 'original_language'])]
text_features = np.hstack([title_feature.toarray(), overview_feature.toarray(), tagline_feature.toarray(), production_companies_feature.toarray()])
svm_X_train = np.hstack([numerical_features, text_features])
svm_y_train = df_train['rate_category']

svm_classifier = SVC(kernel='linear')  # Linear kernel is used, you can choose other kernels too
svm_classifier.fit(svm_X_train, svm_y_train)


Are you sure that all 41 features are required ? Couldn't you apply some feature selection / dimensionality reduction to your dataset ?
Could you try to train with only one (or none) of the bags of words, they might be drastically increasing the computation time

Although in my case, the model would yield a better accuracy because most of the features it's training on are relevant, I did decide to drop a lot of them in the interest of time and see what accuracy I can achieve. Then I'll try a different set of features later on. I'll try a combination or none of the BoW as well to see what I get.

How did it go ? Did you had time to train with other set of features ?
Btw - you're true, especially with newcomers that do not get the codes/rules people are getting crazy

Your answer did help quite a bit. I trained a model using just 1 feature and 500 rows. It trained in 15 mins. Although the accuracy was insanely bad (understandable), I was able to ascertain that there was nothing wrong with my code. I have identified 8 features that are important and will be using those to train. Just not sure how long it would take for 100k rows though.

Since you are learning a linear model, you might want to use sklearn.svm.LinearSVC instead, which is based on liblinear and can learn way faster. In particular you can set the number of iterations of an underlying solver and thus trade speed for accuracy.

I did come across this option as well. But I couldn't really understand the difference as both use the linear kernel? Didn't realize there was difference in computation speed. Could you please point me in the right direction to understand the key difference between these two? Thanks!

They use different implementations. Liblinear is optimized for linear solutions, and does it very well. The other implementation is more generic, but doesn't exploit speedups linear kernel can provide. that's all
